# Mac: start automatically when getting power

Tags: mac, boot

I'm having a Mac mini (Mid 2011) behind a usually switched-off power-outlet. I want the Mac to automatically start when I switch on the power (like I can configure for normal PCs in the BIOS) without having to press the power button on the Mac.

In the System Preferences' "Energy Saver" page the option "Start up automatically after a power failure" is selected. IIRC, this only works if the Mac was not shut down correctly.

Comment: Technically speaking its “Wake On LAN” that is working in your Mac Mini. There are possibilities to Wake on LAN Mac machine but i’m not sure through power on the power outlet. If you can give the version of MAC you are running, we can check for the possibilities.

Comment: Isn't "Wake on LAN" only related to network access from outside? I'm using a "Mac Mini (Mid 2011)".

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/158654/how-to-force-mac-to-into-dirty-shutdown-state-on-every-power-off

Comment: Are the answers in the other question still valid 4 years later with more recent OS X versions? Does that mean no one switches off the power of a Mac mini and finds it uncomfortable to switch it on AND press the power button (where PCs can do it since AGES)?